# Conway's Game of Life in Tkinter crashing with exit code 3489660927 or exit code 0

Tags: python, tkinter

I am currently trying to make a recreation of Conway's Game of Life in Python using Tkinter. Using my current code, it lags and eventually crashes and the exit codes i have gotten so far are exit code 0 and exit code 3489660927. I don't really know what's happening. Here is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from time import sleep

class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master = None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        self.playing = False;
        self.spaces = [[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None], [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None], [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None], [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None], [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None], [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None], [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None], [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None], [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None], [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]]
        self.maxRows = 10
        self.maxColumns = 10
        self.drawSpaces()
        self.clickedrow = 0
        self.clickedcolumn = 0
        self.neighbors = 0
        
    def getNeighbors(self, row, column):
        new = []
        for r in range(max(0, row-1), min(self.maxRows, row+2)):
            for c in range(max(0, column-1), min(self.maxColumns, column+2)):
                if (r, c) != (row, column):
                    new.append(self.spaces[r][c])
        return new
    
    def drawSpaces(self):
        for r in range(10):
            for c in range(10):
                self.spaces[r][c] = tk.Button(text = '', width = 4, height = 2, bg = 'light grey', command = lambda r = r, c = c: self.change(r,c))
                self.spaces[r][c].grid(row = r, column = c)
        self.play = tk.Button(text = 'Start', width = 30, height = 2, command = lambda: self.start())
        self.play.grid(row = 0, column = 11)
    def change(self, row, column):
        if self.spaces[row][column].cget('bg') == 'light grey':
            self.spaces[row][column].config(bg = 'black')
        elif self.spaces[row][column].cget('bg') == 'black':
            self.spaces[row][column].config(bg = 'light grey')
    def start(self):
        if self.play.cget('text') == 'Start':
            self.play.config(text = 'Stop')
        else:
            self.drawSpaces()
            return
        while self.play.cget('text') == 'Stop':
            for r in range(10):
                for c in range(10):
                    self.neighbors = 0
                    neighborlist = self.getNeighbors(r, c)
                
                    for i in range(len(neighborlist)):
                        if neighborlist[i].cget('bg') == 'black':
                            self.neighbors += 1
                    
                    if self.spaces[r][c].cget('bg') == 'light grey':
                        if self.neighbors == 3:
                            self.spaces[r][c].config(bg = 'black')
                        
                    elif self.spaces[r][c].cget('bg') == 'black':
                        if self.neighbors != 2 or self.neighbors != 3:
                            self.spaces[r][c].config(bg = 'light grey')
                    sleep(0.5)
        
        
        

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Conway\'s Game Of Life')
app = Application(master = root)
app.mainloop()
```

What I'm thinking is it might have to handle to many calculations at once, but that's only a guess. If it helps, I'm using Thonny to run my code.

Answer (score 2):

The reason the gui is frozen is because your while loop is blocking the tkinter gui event loop for updating the gui. Using while loops and functions like time.sleep are typically discouraged in GUI programs because they are considered blocking operations.

An example of this is when you click the start button your code changes the text from "start" to "stop". However the user never actually sees this happen because immediately after changing the text, you start a never ending while loop keeping the GUI from actually updating the text.

What you can do instead is schedule events so that the GUI remains in control. For example you can use the `Frame.after` method in order to schedule the the process of checking each square and changing it's color according to the rules of life.  You can do this by splitting that portion of the `start` method into a separate function and using `self.after(..,..)`  to trigger it with a timeout event.

In addition to the points made above there is also a couple flaws in your algorithm.  The most obvious being that you initially are setting each square to be `light grey` color so when your algorithm goes to check which squares need to change colors, it won't find any because they are all the same color.  Instead you should randomly assign the color when initializing each of the squares.

Here is an example:

```
import tkinter as tk
from time import sleep
import random

color = lambda: random.choice(['black', 'light grey'])

class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master = None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        self.playing = False;
        self.spaces = [[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None], [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None], [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None], [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None], [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None], [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None], [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None], [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None], [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None], [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]]
        self.maxRows = 10
        self.maxColumns = 10
        self.drawSpaces()
        self.clickedrow = 0
        self.clickedcolumn = 0
        self.neighbors = 0

    def getNeighbors(self, row, column):
        new = []
        for r in range(max(0, row-1), min(self.maxRows, row+2)):
            for c in range(max(0, column-1), min(self.maxColumns, column+2)):
                if (r, c) != (row, column):
                    new.append(self.spaces[r][c])
        return new


    def drawSpaces(self):
        for r in range(10):
            for c in range(10):
                self.spaces[r][c] = tk.Button(text = '', width = 4, height = 2, bg = color(), command = lambda r = r, c = c: self.change(r,c))
                self.spaces[r][c].grid(row = r, column = c)
        self.play = tk.Button(text = 'Start', width = 30, height = 2, command = lambda: self.start())
        self.play.grid(row = 0, column = 11)


    def change(self, row, column):
        if self.spaces[row][column].cget('bg') == 'light grey':
            self.spaces[row][column].config(bg = 'black')
        elif self.spaces[row][column].cget('bg') == 'black':
            self.spaces[row][column].config(bg = 'light grey')

    def start(self):
        if self.play.cget('text') == 'Start':
            self.play.config(text = 'Stop')
        else:
            self.drawSpaces()
            return
        self.after(1000, self.turn)

    def turn(self):
        if self.play.cget('text') != 'Stop':
            return
        for r in range(10):
            for c in range(10):
                self.neighbors = 0
                neighborlist = self.getNeighbors(r, c)
                for i in range(len(neighborlist)):
                    if neighborlist[i].cget('bg') == 'black':
                        self.neighbors += 1
                if self.spaces[r][c].cget('bg') == 'light grey':
                    if self.neighbors == 3:
                        self.spaces[r][c].config(bg = 'black')
                elif self.spaces[r][c].cget('bg') == 'black':
                    if self.neighbors != 2 or self.neighbors != 3:
                        self.spaces[r][c].config(bg = 'light grey')
        self.after(1000, self.turn)

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Conway\'s Game Of Life')
app = Application(master = root)
app.mainloop()
```